# Scala Spark SQL : java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: LINE_TYPE

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have a scala spark sql which was running fine in spark 2.1. While testing on spark 2.3, some part of the code it failed with the error:

> java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: LINE_TYPE

where `LINE_TYPE` is actually one of the column

see the code, from temp 1 - temp 7 was running good (I have tried to do `.show()` for every temp_*Df), but temp 8 is throwing error, is it too much sub query or self join is not allowed in 2.3?

I have tried repartition temp_Df7 which is the source for temp 8

```
var temp_7Df = spark.sql("select * from temp_7Df").repartition($"LINE_TYPE",$"ORGN_CODE",$"BATCH_NO")
temp_7Df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_7Df")
```

i still have no clue happen, appreciate anyone to shed some light

**adding temp7 to persistent storage

```
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
var temp_7Rdd = temp_df
temp_7Rdd.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
import spark.implicits._
temp_7Rdd.toDF()
temp_7Rdd.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_7Df")
```

Code (Partial)

```
spark-shell --jars /intake/jar/PPG_HIVE_UDFS-0.0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar --conf spark.executor.memory=15G --conf spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer --conf spark.executor.instances=20 --conf spark.driver.memory=8g --conf spark.executor.cores=4 --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true --conf spark.network.timeout=800 --conf spark.sql.cbo.joinReorder.enabled=true --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.executorIdleTimeout=90s --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.intialExecutors=10 --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=15 --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=40 --conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true --name application --queue queue

spark.conf.set("spark.eventLog.enabled", "true")
spark.conf.set("spark.io.compression.codec", "snappy")
spark.conf.set("spark.rdd.compress", "true")
spark.conf.set("spark.shuffle.service.enabled", "true")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreOrc", "true")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.orc.enabled", "true")
spark.conf.set("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.orc.enableVectorizedReader", "true")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.cbo.enabled", "true")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "2100")

val crc64 = spark.sql("""CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION CRC64 AS 'some UDF'""")

var temp_df = spark.sql("""select from source""")
temp_df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_1Df")

var temp_df = spark.sql("""select from source""")
temp_df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_2Df")

var temp_df = spark.sql("""select from source and temp_Df2""")
temp_df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_3Df")

var temp_df = spark.sql("""select from source and temp_Df2, temp_Df3""")
temp_df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_4Df")

var temp_df = spark.sql("""select from source and temp_Df1, temp_Df2, temp_Df3""")
temp_df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_5Df")

var temp_df = spark.sql("""SELECT * FROM temp_4Df
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM temp_5Df""")
temp_df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_6Df")

var temp_df = spark.sql("""select from source and temp_6Df""")
temp_df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_7Df")

var temp_df = spark.sql("""SELECT 
/*+ STREAMTABLE(AL) */ 
AL.ORGN_CODE,
AL.BATCH_NO,
AL.inventory_item_id OUTPUT_inventory_ITEM_ID,
AL.LINE_NO,
AL.LINE_TYPE,
AL.LOT_ID OUTPUT_LOT_ID,
AL.BATCH_QTY OUTPUT_ACTUAL_QTY,
AL.Batch_qty_Primary_uom OUTPUT_ACTUAL_QTY_PRIMARY_UOM
FROM temp_7Df AL JOIN
(SELECT CC.ORGN_CODE, CC.BATCH_NO, MIN(CC.LINE_NO) LINE_NO
 FROM
   (
    SELECT AA.ORGN_CODE, AA.BATCH_NO, MAX(AA.BATCH_QTY) BATCH_QTY
    FROM temp_7Df AA
    WHERE AA.LINE_TYPE=1
    GROUP BY AA.ORGN_CODE,AA.BATCH_NO
    ) BB JOIN
temp_7Df CC ON CC.ORGN_CODE=BB.ORGN_CODE
AND CC.BATCH_NO=BB.BATCH_NO
AND CC.BATCH_QTY=BB.BATCH_QTY
WHERE CC.LINE_TYPE=1
GROUP BY CC.ORGN_CODE,CC.BATCH_NO
) DD ON AL.ORGN_CODE = DD.ORGN_CODE
AND AL.BATCH_NO = DD.BATCH_NO
AND AL.LINE_NO = DD.LINE_NO
WHERE AL.LINE_TYPE = 1""")

temp_df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_8Df")

var testresult = spark.sql("""select * from temp_8Df""")
testresult.show()
```

Error Code (partial)

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: execute, tree:
Exchange hashpartitioning(ITEM_ID#1364, LINE_NO#1218, BATCH_ID#1216, 2100)
+- *(121) Project [plant_code#2919, BATCH_NO#2920, MATERIAL_DETAIL_ID#1215, batch_id#1216, LINE_NO#1218, LINE_TYPE#1220, actual_qty#1224, ITEM_ID#1364]
   +- *(121) BroadcastHashJoin [ITEM_UM#1222], [UM_CODE#1646], Inner, BuildRight
      :- *(121) Project [plant_code#2919, BATCH_NO#2920, MATERIAL_DETAIL_ID#1215, batch_id#1216, LINE_NO#1218, LINE_TYPE#1220, item_um#1222, actual_qty#1224, ITEM_ID#1364]
      :  +- *(121) BroadcastHashJoin [ITEM_UM#1370], [UM_CODE#48], Inner, BuildRight
      :     :- *(121) Project [plant_code#2919, BATCH_NO#2920, MATERIAL_DETAIL_ID#1215, batch_id#1216, LINE_NO#1218, LINE_TYPE#1220, item_um#1222, actual_qty#1224, ITEM_ID#1364, ITEM_UM#1370]
      :     :  +- *(121) BroadcastHashJoin [ITEM_ID#1364], [ITEM_ID#1630], LeftOuter, BuildRight
      :     :     :- *(121) Project [plant_code#2919, BATCH_NO#2920, MATERIAL_DETAIL_ID#1215, batch_id#1216, LINE_NO#1218, LINE_TYPE#1220, item_um#1222, actual_qty#1224, ITEM_ID#1364, ITEM_UM#1370]
      :     :     :  +- *(121) BroadcastHashJoin [ITEM_ID#1364], [ITEM_ID#1608], LeftOuter, BuildRight
      :     :     :     :- *(121) Project [plant_code#2919, BATCH_NO#2920, MATERIAL_DETAIL_ID#1215, batch_id#1216, LINE_NO#1218, LINE_TYPE#1220, item_um#1222, actual_qty#1224, ITEM_ID#1364, ITEM_UM#1370]
      :     :     :     :  +- *(121) BroadcastHashJoin [ITEM_ID#1364], [ITEM_ID#6], LeftOuter, BuildRight
      :     :     :     :     :- *(121) Project [plant_code#2919, BATCH_NO#2920, MATERIAL_DETAIL_ID#1215, batch_id#1216, LINE_NO#1218, LINE_TYPE#1220, item_um#1222, actual_qty#1224, ITEM_ID#1364, ITEM_UM#1370]
      :     :     :     :     :  +- *(121) BroadcastHashJoin [ORGN_CODE#1287, ITEM_ID#1364], [ORGN_CODE#1493, ITEM_ID#1554], Inner, BuildRight
      :     :     :     :     :     :- *(121) Project [plant_code#2919, BATCH_NO#2920, MATERIAL_DETAIL_ID#1215, batch_id#1216, LINE_NO#1218, LINE_TYPE#1220, item_um#1222, actual_qty#1224, orgn_code#1287, ITEM_ID#1364, ITEM_UM#1370]
      :     :     :     :     :     :  +- *(121) BroadcastHashJoin [ITEM_ID#1219], [ITEM_ID#1364], Inner, BuildRight
      :     :     :     :     :     :     :- *(121) Project [plant_code#2919, BATCH_NO#2920, MATERIAL_DETAIL_ID#1215, batch_id#1216, LINE_NO#1218, item_id#1219, LINE_TYPE#1220, item_um#1222, actual_qty#1224, orgn_code#1287]
      :     :     :     :     :     :     :  +- *(121) BroadcastHashJoin [RECIPE_ID#1286, ORGN_CODE#1287], [RECIPE_ID#1347, ORGN_CODE#1348], LeftOuter, BuildRight
      :     :     :     :     :     :     :     :- *(121) Project [plant_code#2919, BATCH_NO#2920, MATERIAL_DETAIL_ID#1215, batch_id#1216, LINE_NO#1218, item_id#1219, LINE_TYPE#1220, item_um#1222, actual_qty#1224, recipe_id#1286, orgn_code#1287]
      :     :     :     :     :     :     :     :  +- *(121) BroadcastHashJoin [RECIPE_VALIDITY_RULE_ID#2924], [RECIPE_VALIDITY_RULE_ID#1285], Inner, BuildRight
      :     :     :     :     :     :     :     :     :- *(121) Project [plant_code#2919, BATCH_NO#2920, RECIPE_VALIDITY_RULE_ID#2924, MATERIAL_DETAIL_ID#1215, batch_id#1216, LINE_NO#1218, item_id#1219, LINE_TYPE#1220, item_um#1222, actual_qty#1224]
      :     :     :     :     :     :     :     :     :  +- ShuffledHashJoin [BATCH_ID#2918], [BATCH_ID#1216], Inner, BuildLeft
      :     :     :     :     :     :     :     :     :     :- Exchange hashpartitioning(BATCH_ID#2918, 2100)
      :     :     :     :     :     :     :     :     :     :  +- *(110) Project [BATCH_ID#2918, plant_code#2919, BATCH_NO#2920, RECIPE_VALIDITY_RULE_ID#2924]
      :     :     :     :     :     :     :     :     :     :     +- *(110) Filter (((((batch_status#2932 IN (3,4) && (cast(date_format(cast(actual_cmplt_date#2931 as timestamp), yyyyMM, Some(Etc/UTC)) as int) >= 201904)) && isnotnull(BATCH_ID#2918)) && isnotnull(RECIPE_VALIDITY_RULE_ID#2924)) && isnotnull(BATCH_NO#2920)) && isnotnull(plant_code#2919))
      :     :     :     :     :     :     :     :     :     :        +- *(110) FileScan orc conformed_staging.cv_appoea_gme_gme_batch_header[batch_id#2918,plant_code#2919,batch_no#2920,recipe_validity_rule_id#2924,actual_cmplt_date#2931,batch_status#2932] Batched: true, Format: ORC, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[adl://ppgdadatalakeuat.azuredatalakestore.net/data/intake/conformed/staging/fin..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [In(batch_status, [3,4]), IsNotNull(BATCH_ID), IsNotNull(RECIPE_VALIDITY_RULE_ID), IsNotNull(BATC..., ReadSchema: struct<batch_id:string,plant_code:string,batch_no:string,recipe_validity_rule_id:string,actual_cm...
      :     :     :     :     :     :     :     :     :     +- Exchange hashpartitioning(BATCH_ID#1216, 2100)
      :     :     :     :     :     :     :     :     :        +- *(111) Project [MATERIAL_DETAIL_ID#1215, batch_id#1216, LINE_NO#1218, item_id#1219, LINE_TYPE#1220, item_um#1222, actual_qty#1224]
      :     :     :     :     :     :     :     :     :           +- *(111) Filter (((((((isnotnull(CONTRIBUTE_YIELD_IND#1273) && isnotnull(LINE_TYPE#1220)) && (CONTRIBUTE_YIELD_IND#1273 = Y)) && (cast(LINE_TYPE#1220 as int) = 1)) && isnotnull(BATCH_ID#1216)) && isnotnull(ITEM_ID#1219)) && isnotnull(ITEM_UM#1222)) && isnotnull(ACTUAL_QTY#1224))
      :     :     :     :     :     :     :     :     :              +- *(111) FileScan orc conformed_staging.cv_appoea_gme_gme_material_details[material_detail_id#1215,batch_id#1216,line_no#1218,item_id#1219,line_type#1220,item_um#1222,actual_qty#1224,contribute_yield_ind#1273] Batched: true, Format: ORC, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[adl://ppgdadatalakeuat.azuredatalakestore.net/data/intake/conformed/staging/fin..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(contribute_yield_ind), IsNotNull(LINE_TYPE), EqualTo(contribute_yield_ind,Y), IsNotNul..., ReadSchema: struct<material_detail_id:string,batch_id:string,line_no:string,item_id:string,line_type:string,i...
      :     :     :     :     :     :     :     :     +- ReusedExchange [recipe_validity_rule_id#1285, recipe_id#1286, orgn_code#1287], BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, string, true]))
      :     :     :     :     :     :     :     +- ReusedExchange [recipe_id#1347, orgn_code#1348], BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, string, true], input[1, string, true]))
      :     :     :     :     :     :     +- ReusedExchange [ITEM_ID#1364, ITEM_UM#1370], BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, string, true]))
      :     :     :     :     :     +- ReusedExchange [orgn_code#1493, item_id#1554], BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, string, true], input[1, string, true]))
      :     :     :     :     +- ReusedExchange [ITEM_ID#6], BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, string, true]))
      :     :     :     +- ReusedExchange [item_id#1608], BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, string, true]))
      :     :     +- ReusedExchange [item_id#1630], BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, string, true]))
      :     +- ReusedExchange [UM_CODE#48], BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, string, true]))
      +- ReusedExchange [UM_CODE#1646], BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, string, true]))

  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:56)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.doExecute(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:119)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.inputRDDs(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:371)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SortExec.inputRDDs(SortExec.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:605)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.SortMergeJoinExec.doExecute(SortMergeJoinExec.scala:150)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.inputRDDs(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:371)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.inputRDDs(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:41)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:605)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnionExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:557)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnionExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:557)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:285)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnionExec.doExecute(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:557)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.prepareShuffleDependency(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:92)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:128)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:119)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:52)
  ... 228 more
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: execute, tree:
Exchange hashpartitioning(BATCH_ID#1216, 2100)
+- *(111) Project [MATERIAL_DETAIL_ID#1215, batch_id#1216, LINE_NO#1218, item_id#1219, LINE_TYPE#1220, item_um#1222, actual_qty#1224]
   +- *(111) Filter (((((((isnotnull(CONTRIBUTE_YIELD_IND#1273) && isnotnull(LINE_TYPE#1220)) && (CONTRIBUTE_YIELD_IND#1273 = Y)) && (cast(LINE_TYPE#1220 as int) = 1)) && isnotnull(BATCH_ID#1216)) && isnotnull(ITEM_ID#1219)) && isnotnull(ITEM_UM#1222)) && isnotnull(ACTUAL_QTY#1224))
      +- *(111) FileScan orc conformed_staging.cv_appoea_gme_gme_material_details[material_detail_id#1215,batch_id#1216,line_no#1218,item_id#1219,line_type#1220,item_um#1222,actual_qty#1224,contribute_yield_ind#1273] Batched: true, Format: ORC, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[adl://ppgdadatalakeuat.azuredatalakestore.net/data/intake/conformed/staging/fin..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(contribute_yield_ind), IsNotNull(LINE_TYPE), EqualTo(contribute_yield_ind,Y), IsNotNul..., ReadSchema: struct<material_detail_id:string,batch_id:string,line_no:string,item_id:string,line_type:string,i...

  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:56)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.doExecute(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:119)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.ShuffledHashJoinExec.doExecute(ShuffledHashJoinExec.scala:67)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.inputRDDs(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:371)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.inputRDDs(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:41)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.inputRDDs(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:76)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.inputRDDs(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:41)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.inputRDDs(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:76)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.inputRDDs(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:41)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.inputRDDs(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:76)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.inputRDDs(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:41)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.inputRDDs(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:76)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.inputRDDs(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:41)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.inputRDDs(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:76)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.inputRDDs(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:41)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.inputRDDs(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:76)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.inputRDDs(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:41)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.inputRDDs(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:76)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.inputRDDs(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:41)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.inputRDDs(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:76)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.inputRDDs(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:41)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.inputRDDs(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:76)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.inputRDDs(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:41)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:605)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.prepareShuffleDependency(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:92)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:128)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:119)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:52)
  ... 278 more
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: LINE_TYPE
  at scala.collection.MapLike$class.default(MapLike.scala:228)
  at scala.collection.AbstractMap.default(Map.scala:59)
  at scala.collection.MapLike$class.apply(MapLike.scala:141)
  at scala.collection.AbstractMap.apply(Map.scala:59)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFilters$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$orc$OrcFilters$$buildSearchArgument(OrcFilters.scala:198)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFilters$$anonfun$2.apply(OrcFilters.scala:69)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFilters$$anonfun$2.apply(OrcFilters.scala:68)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:344)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFilters$.createFilter(OrcFilters.scala:68)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFileFormat.buildReaderWithPartitionValues(OrcFileFormat.scala:145)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec.inputRDD$lzycompute(DataSourceScanExec.scala:297)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec.inputRDD(DataSourceScanExec.scala:295)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec.inputRDDs(DataSourceScanExec.scala:315)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FilterExec.inputRDDs(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.inputRDDs(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:41)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:605)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.prepareShuffleDependency(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:92)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:128)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:119)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:52)
  ... 323 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is already somewhere before, temp_8Df is throwing error, because that is the place where you are triggering the actions "show()"

Before that spark is only forming the DAG for lazy execution.

Only when it received an action the actual execution began, and it threw an error. So try to do a show in earlier steps and you can debug it.

Comment: apology for not making the statement clear, I have tried to do show for every temp_*Df and did not throw any error, not until temp_8Df only the error is thrown

Comment: Write temp_7Df to an intermediate persisent storage or a hive table. And use that table in the next query. That should solve the issue.

Comment: Dear Partha, thanks for your advise, I am trying to write it to persistent storage. see my edit above under section **adding temp7 to persistent storage. I have not got a successful return yet, still getting the same NoSuchElementException. Did I code wrongly? I will move on to try on hive table now..

Comment: writing to hive table and reading from it is working fine, but writing to hive table take longer time compare to persistent storage.. i would take it as my last resort.. but for the persistent storage part, am i doing it right?

Comment: Once persisted, use the persisted dataframe, and you can directly persist the dataframe without converting to a rdd:
      `import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel;

       val temp7df_persisted=temp_df.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK);
       import spark.implicits._;
       temp7df_persisted.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_7Df");`




I put in semi-colons to mark the end of line.
But also remember, for huge multi joins with multiple shuffles, and large datasets, the only resolution might be writing to a hive table. Please let us know, if this solves your issue.

Comment: i am afraid it is still not working, the similar error still persist, maybe I can only write to hive table? But any idea why is the original code worked on spark 2.1 but not in 2.3?

Comment: The details will be somewhere in the execution engine details that have been changed within spark, with the version upgrade.
But from a developers perspective it is tough to determine.

Comment: Yes, you can absolutely use this workaround to write to a Hive table. I hope it takes a bit more time, not very much, because spark to hive communication (data write and retrieval) is also actually very fast. Happy Coding. And if this solves your issue, could you please also mark this as solved :)